# Entering data from a cell across specific Time periods

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Trying to insert specific data across time period (months/years) but specific months within that time frame, i.e., 2nd, 13th, 25th, 37th and 49th.

More specifically adding residuals to these months.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The columns read like:

`1/20/16, 2/20/2016, 3/20/2016 thru 12/20/2023`.

If I have a contract start date of 3/20/2016 and end date of 3/20/2019, I would like to add the "$750.00" into the 2nd , 13th and every 12 month period after that date.

Comment: Looking for a good formula

Comment: Sandy, it's not clear what you're asking.  Please edit your question to include a specific example, along with the result that you're looking for.  The curly brackets in the bar above the editing window are used to format code (or Excel formulas) in a readable form.

Comment: I have months (2016 thru 2023) across columns, trying to add a specific amount ($750.00) in the 2nd, 13th, 25th, 37th, and 49th month from a specific start date.

Comment: Best to edit your initial question yo make it clearer (instead of adding comments)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(COLUMN()<>3,OR(COLUMN()=4,(MOD(COLUMN(),12)=3))),750,"")
```

(Edited to prevent the column with the start date from getting $750.)

The IF() statement is true if the column number is not 3 AND if either the column number is 4 OR if the column number has a remainder of 3 when divided by 12.  Those columns get 750, and others get blank ("").

The row with the formula should be formatted as currency.

Since all the dates are 12 months apart except for the first two, the MOD() function gets everything except the 2nd month.

The formula above works when the start date of 3/20/16 is in Column C.

Comment: I have the residual already calculated.  The columns read like 1/20/16, 2/20/2016,3/20/2016 thru 12/20/2023.  If I have a contract start date of 3/20/2016 and end 3/20/2019 would like to add the "$750.00" into the 2nd , 13th and every 12 month periods after that date, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  If you're counting columns starting with 3/20/16, change the formula so instead of 2 in the first part, it has the number of that column +2.  Type =Column() to see what the column number is.  You'll also have to change the remainder in the second part (currently 1) to whatever is left when you divide the other desired column numbers by 12.

Comment: @SandyP, if this answer was helpful, see [this link](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: That also adds 750 in the 1st month — you need to exclude that.